# Construct representation of Lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

Consider the 3D Lie algebra with the following defined:

$
[x,y] = z
$,
$
[x,z]=0
$,
$
[y,z]=0
$

From this, I want to get a little help how to start finding a 3D representation by $3\times 3$ real matrices. I don't know how to begin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Lie algebra is 3-dimensional, you can consider the adjoint representation.

If we write $L$ your Lie algebra, then for each $x\in L$ there is a linear map $$\operatorname{ad}(x):y\in L\mapsto [x,y]\in L,$$ and this defines a map $$\operatorname{ad}:L\to\operatorname{End}(L)$$ which you can easily check to be a representation.

(Yoy could also consider the trivial representation, but that is slightly less entertaining...)

Comment: Thanks, I'm taking a very basic introductory course in this. Could you tell me if this is the trivial (or a correct) representation? $$ad_{e_1}=0$$, $$ad_{e_2}=0$$ and $$ad_{e_3}= 
  \left( {\begin{array}{ccc}
   0 & 1 & 0\\
   -1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array} } \right)
$$

Comment: It feels very counter-intuitive.

Comment: If $e_1$, $e_2$ and $e_3$ are $x$, $y$ and $z$, respectively, that is not right. We have $ad_z=0$, for example.

Comment: Ok, then I don't understand. Because what I have done now is to construct it such as it fulfill: $$[e_i, e_j]=\sum_{k=1}^3 f_{ij}^ke_k$$ When I calculated the matrix elements using this I got the three matrices above.

Comment: Well, then you make a mistake. You wrote that $ad_{e_1}=0$, and that means that $[e_1,u]=0$ for all $u\in L$; likewise, your second equation mean sthat $[e_2,u]=0$ for all $u\in L$. This tells us that the center of the Lie algebra has dimension at least two (for $e_1$ and $e_2$ are contained there) Yet the Lie algebra you described in your question has a $1$-dimensional center.

Comment: We have $[x,x]=0$, $[x,y]=z$ and $[x,z]=0$, so with respect to the ordered basis $\{x,y,z\}$ we have $ad_x=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}$. Similarly, $[y,x]=-z$, $[y,y]=0$ and $[y,z]=0$, so that $ad_y=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\-1&0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Finally, as $[z,x]=[z,y]=[z,z]=0$, $ad_z$ is the zero matrix.

Comment: Thank you Mariano, will have to look at this more when I get home.